# É possível gerar o arquivo XSD a partir do XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

A dúvida é como gerar o arquivo .[xsd](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema) a partir do xml ? 
Estava analisando esse tutorial [C# - Operações Básicas com XML](http://www.macoratti.net/12/04/c_obxml1.htm) e aqui não diz como. 
 É possível ?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<arquivoxml>
<SinteseCadastral>
  <Documento>string</Documento>
  <Nome>string</Nome>
  <NomeMae>string</NomeMae>
  <NomeFantasia>string</NomeFantasia>
</SinteseCadastral>
<TotalOcorrencias>int</TotalOcorrencias>
<ValorTotalOcorrencias>string</ValorTotalOcorrencias>
<AlertaDocumentos>
  <NumeroMensagem>string</NumeroMensagem>
  <TotalMensagens>string</TotalMensagens>
  <TipoDocumento>string</TipoDocumento>
  <NumeroDocumento>string</NumeroDocumento>
  <MotivoOcorrencia>string</MotivoOcorrencia>
  <DataOcorrencia>string</DataOcorrencia>
  <TelefonesContato>
    <Telefone>string</Telefone>
  </TelefonesContato>
  <TelefonesContato>
    <Telefone>string</Telefone>
  </TelefonesContato>
  <Mensagem>string</Mensagem>
</AlertaDocumentos>
<PendenciasInternas>
</arquivoxml>
```

Comment: Tem como por uma referência para quem não conhece o que é xsd?

Comment: Não creio que não tenha como "gerar", no caso é vc que deve escrever e criar as definições do XSD para o seu xml.